# Negative Reciprocals

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the negative reciprocal of (-1 + n) / n? I know how to convert simple fractions (such as 1/2) to their negative reciprocals, however, I don't know what to do if there is an extra element (such as adding 1 to the numerator). How would it work?

Comment: What is the "negative reciprical"?

Comment: $$-\frac{n}{-1 + n}$$ Or if you prefer: $$\frac{n}{1 - n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reciprocal of $ \frac{-1+n}{n}$ is $ \frac{n}{-1+n}$. Thus, what you are looking for is given by $ \frac{n}{1-n}$.